# Integrate Github with Amazon SQS with webhooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, github-webhook

Github has deprecated **integrations and services** and suggests to use [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) or [GitHub Apps](https://developer.github.com/apps/differences-between-apps/#about-github-apps/) instead.
My doubt here is that AWS SQS requires autenthicated requests (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-api-request-authentication.html) and I can't achieve it through Github webhooks.

Does anybody has an ideia on this or have some solution that would like to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest configuring an API Gateway endpoint that triggers an AWS Lambda function, which inserts into your SQS queue. Then you would configure a Github webhook to hit the API Gateway endpoint.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to integrate API Gateway directly with SQS?

Comment: You can try setting up an API Gateway as a Service Proxy for SQS.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up the amazon API gateway with the full access role for sqs and create an API in that to post the webhook in SQS queue.

[Webhook Processing with API Gateway and SQS](https://medium.com/@andy.tarpley/webhook-processing-with-api-gateway-and-sqs-f8309411913a). This will help.